# Nested routes in Padrino

Tags: ruby, routes, padrino

I want to group routes into hierarchies. To that end I have created a top level controller thus:

```
MyApp.controllers :group do
  disable :layout

  get '/' do
    {'dummy' => 'value'}.as_json
  end
end
```

Now I want to create routes with `:group` as parent thus:

```
MyApp.controllers :items, :parent => :group do
  disable :layout

  get '/', :provides => :json do
    # get list of items
  end
end
```

My problem is that I can access `localhost:port/group` (`200 OK`) from my REST client but I cannot access `localhost:port/group/items` (`404 NOT FOUND`).

Everything works beautifully if I remove the `:parent` option. My padrino version 0.10.5.5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The way nested routes work is different than what you're trying to do.

When you use `:parent`, it expects the parent resource to be identified somehow. For instance:

```
MyApp.controllers :items, :parent => :group do
  get :index do
    # returns list of items for a group
  end
end
```

Will generate the following route:

```
"/group/#{params[:group_id]}/items"
```

It expects you to specify which group you're talking about in order to fetch the items for that specific group.

That's why it says it cannot find `"/group/items"`, it's not the route that you create by using `:parent => :group`, you're not passing a `:group_id` in the params.

If you really want to use `"/group/items"` then your items controller should look like:

```
MyApp.controllers :items do
  get '/group/items' do
    # returns list of items
  end
end
```